# How can I mount host directory as container volume for mongodb container?

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I would like to create docker-compose configuration for scenario mentioned below for docker containers:-

1) I have Ubuntu14.04 installed in Azure box. I have installed mongodbversion 3.2 in host OS ie Ubuntu 14.04.
2) Now, I will create total of 6 containers(nginx, web-app, redis, mongodb, workers, data-container using image from mongodb container) explained as:-

```
i) Data-container that mounts the directory where monogdb3.2 installed in host Ubuntu writes data (what is the absolute full path for directory where mongodb stores or writes data ?)  

ii) A mongodb-container that serves as db-backend for web-app container. This mongodb-container should use volume mounted in data-container.  

iii) mongodb-container should write data in directory on host Ubuntu ie the directory where mongodb3.2 installed in host Ubuntu writes data or directory mounted in data-container.  

iv) I will stop mongod daemon installed in host ubuntu from running automatically and free the port for db-container to use.  

v) If i delete and remove containers, I will start the mongod daemon in host Ubuntu and can easily access db and data inside directory.
```

So, basically I would like to know that,

Is the steps mentioned above are feasible enough to easily persist data for backups or future use, if not than what would be the proper way ?

Also, how can I create data-container that will not run any app and will only serve as volume or directory provider for data persistence ?

Also, I would like to get guide or tutorial about docker and it's working in an easy and easily understandable manner that can teach docker concepts in a proper and understandable way ?

Hoping my problem explanation make sense. Thankyou. Happy Coding.